# Unable to Set up DHCP and TFTP on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, dhcp, dhcp-server, tftp

I want to transfer my kernel image to beaglebone black, and the guide mentions that I should have already set up DHCP and tftp on the host machine.

I have set up the TFTP using:

> sudo apt-get install tftpd-hpa tftp-hpa
>
> sudo vim /etc/default/tftpd-hpa
>
> TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
>
> TFTP_DIRECTORY="your-ftp-root-directory"
>
> TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
>
> TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure"
>
> sudo service tftpd restart

Also I need a DHCP server on host so It can assign IP to BBBlack.

SO I followed:

> sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
>
> sudo /etc/init.d/networking/restart
>
> nano -w /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
>
> default-lease-time 600;
>
> max-lease-time 7200;
>
> option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
>
> option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
>
> option routers 192.168.1.254;
>
> option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2;
>
> option domain-name "mydomain.example";
>
> subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
>
> range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.100;
>
> range 192.168.1.150 192.168.1.200;
>
> } `
>
> ls /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
>
> INTERFACES "eth0"

```html
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:ae:15:85:ae  
          inet6 addr: fe80::223:aeff:fe15:85ae/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1462 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:279343 (279.3 KB)
          Interrupt:16
```

/etc/network/interface

```html
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        up service dhcp3-server restart
```

Yet. The DHCP is not getting setup.

Please suggest where I may be going wrong

Answer (score 1):

Try Changing the following configurations in the `/etc/network/interface`

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

for more details [click here.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/)

Comment: If I change static to DHCP, won't I require a static IP for the new DHCP server, i.e my Ubuntu machine

Comment: No It will automatically assign an IP to your DHCP server.

Comment: Read this for more information...https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/dhcp.html